# How to deeplink to a Profile in my iOS Xing App?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, xing

I would like to deeplink to my xing profile within my application. 
I know how to open the iOS Xing App in my code, but I can't figure out how to deeplink to my own profile for example. 
Does anyone know the URL route?

```
    let appScheme = "Xing://profile/[username]"
    let appSchemeURL = URL(string: appScheme)

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appSchemeURL!) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(appSchemeURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

That's how I tried it, but all it does is, it opens the app on the initial screen.

Comment: I use some deep link. But i just read some key from the url send in the `openUrl` function in `AppDelegate` and open view based on what the key say.

Answer (score 3):

The app scheme has to be either `xing://profiles/[username]` or `xing://profiles/[userId]`. Then it should work.

Comment: Thanks. It works for opening profile pages. But to deep link to company page?

Comment: You have to redirect to the company page by yourself. By analyzing the components the path of the URI. Then you can decide to any page you want.